# error when make the masterpage , publish major version

Tags: sharepoint-online

error when  make the masterpage , publish major version , The same can't make CheckIn or CheckOut

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The last screenshot is duplicated. did you mean to attach a screenshot of the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

In your screen shot actual error is missing. However, in general before publishing the master page first you need to submit for **approval**, then once it is approved, you can go with **publishing**.

Please read the below statement about master page publishing :

"**If you are an Editor**, you will need an Approver to approve your changes and then publish the page. To submit a page for approval to be published by an Approver: after Checking In a page, go to the **Publish** tab next to Page in the ribbon and click **Submit**."

Source : For details about the master page publishing, refer to the below article :

[Submitting, Approving and Publishing](https://resources.depaul.edu/sharepoint/sharepoint-basics/Pages/saving-checking-in-publishing.aspx)